# WP8 HTML5 app cookies

Tags: windows-phone-8

My app is completely html CSS and JavaScript. I am running into a little problem because I would like the user to be able to use my webpage from the browser or use the app and maintain the cookies between the two.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, this is not possible because the `WebBrowser` control used in your hybrid app does not share anything with the Internet Explorer. They are completely separated and each one is sandboxed.

This also prevents other applications from reusing such cookies.